# Database for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am making a site in which we have four types of users and admin have all privileges.

1) Admin

2) Client

3) Co-Admin

4) Developer

Can u suggest how do I make database in order to decide different privillage as per user types.

Comment: What are you programming the *site* in? If you use an existing framework to build the site, many have solved this problem for you already.

Comment: i am making this in code igniter .... this is my first project in CI ... can u help me put

Comment: what field i had to cover in database to solve this issue of privillages ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter -- Best implementation for ACL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556293/codeigniter-best-implementation-for-acl)

Answer (score 1):

Have a table of roles (id, role_name) and a many-many bridge table (user_id, role_id).

Then use the standard techniques for implementing [a many-to-many relationship](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) between them.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i hope this instructions could help you ,correct me if 'm wrong

1.Maintain a table User Roles for example  {1 Admin , 2 Client,3 Developer},

2.Maintain a table Accessibility for example {1 Read,2 Write}

3.Maintain a individual table Role_Access for example {User_id1,Access_id}

Comment: @ Vaibhav Agarwal ...What else you are expecting ? Create the database and design the table with the required fields.

Comment: actually admin see all functionality an modify any field ..... and client only update the consern field and so developer .... I not able to decide how we fix this and how ?

Comment: Create a separate access policies for pages/fields and assign needed policies to the users and admin

Comment: WC to SO ...If found the answer is helpful to you  work in the accept  rate