# Codeigniter and ion_auth - how do I restrict each function to be accessed?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

How do you implement in codeigniter access control? or exempt certain functions to be executed in your controller? 
I am using ion_auth for my authentication system.

I use MY_Controller to check whether the user is logged in: where:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();

        if(!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
           redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

In my suggestion controller:

```
class Suggestion extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Suggestion_model', 'suggestion');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //some codes
    }

    public function settings()
    {
        //some codes
    }
}
```

Now my question is, how do I restrict each function to be accessed?

Let's say if you are a guest you are able to access

```
index.php/suggestion/create
```

and if you are admin, then you can access below controller

```
index.php/suggestion/settings.
```

but if not then you cannot access, please point me in the right direction. thank you.

Comment: Use Access Control Lists See info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556293/codeigniter-best-implementation-for-acl

Comment: any update on this? how can i implement access control in codeigniter?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143313/use-ion-auth-authentication-for-codeigniter-in-another-controller